# Ant, NetBeans Platform project - how to pass command line arguments and access via System.getProperties?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, netbeans-6.9

All,

I have a NetBeans Platform project (*not* just a project I wrote in NetBeans, but one using the [rich client framework provided by NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/)).  I can run the project via an `ant run` command.  Now, I want to pass in an argument that will work its way through `ant` to be accessible via the `System.getProperty` method.

I understand that I need to use a `<sysproperty>` node to actually inject the key/value pair into the runtime environment, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get this to work with the convoluted build tree that NetBeans creates for you (build.xml depends on build-impl.xml, which in turn depends on ${harness.dir}/suite.xml, which in turn depends on ${harness.dir}/run.xml)

The [simplest example](http://ideoplex.com/id/372/setting-java-system-properties-with-ant) I've found is

```
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="prop"
          fork="true">
      <sysproperty key="test.property"
                   value="blue"
                   />
    </java>
  </target>
```

but the problem is that none of my xml files have an easily accessible `<java>` node like that.  I think I've managed to trace the execution flow to where something is actually invoked (in `${harness.dir}/run.xml`)

```
<target name="run" depends="-prepare-as-app,-prepare-as-platform">
        <touch file="${cluster}/.lastModified"/> <!-- #138427 -->
        <property name="run.args" value=""/>
        <property name="run.args.ide" value=""/>
        <property name="run.args.extra" value=""/>
        <condition property="run.args.mac" value="-J-Xdock:name=${app.name}" else="">
            <os family="mac"/>
        </condition>
        <exec osfamily="windows" executable="${run.exe}" failonerror="no" resultproperty="result.prop">
            <arg value="--jdkhome"/>
            <arg file="${run.jdkhome}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args.common}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args.prepared}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args.ide}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args.extra}"/>
        </exec>
        <exec osfamily="unix" dir="." executable="sh"
        failonerror="no" resultproperty="result.prop">
            <arg value="${run.sh}"/>
            <arg value="--jdkhome"/>
            <arg file="${run.jdkhome}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args.common}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args.prepared}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args.ide}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args.extra}"/>
            <arg line="${run.args.mac}"/>
        </exec>
        <fail>
The application is already running within the test user directory.
You must shut it down before trying to run it again.
            <condition>
                <and>
                    <isset property="result.prop" />
                    <or>
                        <!-- unknown option exit code as returned from IDE by org.netbeans.api.sendopts.CommandLine -->
                        <equals arg1="${result.prop}" arg2="50346" />
                        <!-- unknown option exit code as returned from platform app by org.netbeans.CLIHandler -->
                        <equals arg1="${result.prop}" arg2="2" />
                    </or>
                </and>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>
```

As you can see, there is no `<java>` node underneath which I can put my custom sysproperty.  Furthermore, it seems like a very wrong thing to do to have to muck around with harness xml files to inject a property that only affects one of my projects, not all of them.  So what's the correct way to ensure that a command line property I pass to ant run ends up within a NetBeans Platform project?

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder **etc** in the distribution of your RCP app and in that folder is file **yourapp.conf** i think there is an answer you seek. For example from one of mine NB RCP app:

```
# ${HOME} will be replaced by user home directory according to platform
default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/dev"
default_mac_userdir="${HOME}/Library/Application Support/${APPNAME}/dev"

# options used by the launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
# command line switches
default_options="--laf Metal --branding xmled -J-Xms24m -J-Xmx64m"
# for development purposes you may wish to append: -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea

# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
#jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"

# clusters' paths separated by path.separator (semicolon on Windows, colon on Unices)
#extra_clusters=
```

Comment: I don't see this folder.  (and doing a grep for these strings i.e. default_options turns up nothing).  Is this only if you've created an installer?

Comment: build zip dist for example and look inside there is **etc/{name of your application}.conf**. I guess you didn't substituted name of your application when used grep. So if your application is called **Dune** name of the file will be **Dune.conf**. The folder just have to be there.